# Добавления, удаления item из RecyclerView c анимацией

Tags: android, анимация, recyclerview

Добавления, удаления item из RecyclerView. 
Добавить, удалить item я могу, проблема в следующем: с сервера приходит ArrayList c  данными(каждые n секунд ArrayList обновляется), я могу сверять старый и новый список, удалять или добавлять item, может есть что-то встроенное (с анимацией), чтобы не сверять списки, чтобы не городить такой велосипед

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Рекомендованный подход - использование `DiffUtil`. Почитать можно [тут](https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00#.8joliy5dq). Коротко говоря, он подготовит обновление сравнив текущие данные и новый список, анимация работает за счет встроенных `notifyItemChanged`...